# How to create two datepicker using vuejs and momentjs?

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, momentjs

I'm using `moment js` to change the format of my date. I'm trying to create a start and end date to view all the transaction of the customer. I already create the first date. And I want to create another one for my end date. How can I do that? Can somebody help me with my problem? Here's my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/89vwy2od/1/

```
  var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
      date : "",
      date2 : ""
      },
  methods : {
    showDate1 : function() {
    alert(this.date);
    },
    showDate2 : function() {
        alert(this.date2);
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {

   var args = {

        format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'
   };
    this.$nextTick(function() {
        $('.datepicker').datetimepicker(args)
    });

   this.$nextTick(function() {
      $('.time-picker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'LT'
      })
   });
  }
})

 $('.datepicker').on('dp.change', function(event) {
   if (event.date) {
     var date = event.date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
     console.log(date);
     Vue.set(vm, 'date', date);
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution (not optimal) is using 2 different class or different id

```
<div class="col-md-2">
             <input type="text" v-model="date" class="datepicker form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Enter Date 1">{{date}}
              <input type="text" v-model="date2" class="datepicker2 form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Enter Date 1">{{date2}}
              </div>
```

then you need to init 2 twices:

```
this.$nextTick(function() {
            $('.datepicker').datetimepicker(args)
            $('.datepicker2').datetimepicker(args)
        });
```

and

```
$('.datepicker').on('dp.change', function(event) {
  if (event.date) {
    var date = event.date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    console.log(date);
    Vue.set(vm, 'date', date);
  }
});

$('.datepicker2').on('dp.change', function(event) {
  if (event.date) {
    var date = event.date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    console.log(date);
    Vue.set(vm, 'date2', date);
  }
});
```

You can check [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/ittus/yqwshe6o/3/)

A better solution is creating a custom component.